# How to speed up heroku loading rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Heroku seems to be loading my rails app forever. Just wonder if I upgrade to a paid membership on heroku would help? Or is there other way around? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

on Free accounts, the server has to boot each time, if site hasnt been accessed for 30 minutes, the server goes back to sleep. Meaning next time site is visited, it has to boot up.

You can upgrade for $7 to hobby account.

https://www.heroku.com/pricing